# Awk to print matching lines from two unsorted files

Tags: unix, awk

I am trying to compare two files and i need to print the matching lines from both the files.

File 1

```
a;c1|a|data  
a;c2|a|data  
b;c1|b|data  
b;c1|b|data
```

File 2

```
a;c2|a_1|data  
b;c1|b_1|data  
a;c3|a_1|data  
b;c1|b_1|data  
a;c1|a_1|data
```

Output File

```
a;c1|a|data  
a;c2|a|data  
b;c1|b|data  
b;c1|b|data  
a;c2|a_1|data  
b;c1|b_1|data  
b;c1|b_1|data  
a;c1|a_1|data
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: Define **matching lines**.

Comment: what have you tried? Did you try solving this with `join`, or `comm`, or `diff`?   Your sample output doesn't seem to support your problem definition of "print the matching lines from both the files". Please update you Q with improved defintion as well as some attempt to solve your problem. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am looking to compare the two un-sorted files with column 1 & 3 and print the output of both the files. I am sorry for the output as i just copied the files.

Comment: I tried the below command, but it prints only the file1 contents.  awk -F "|" 'NR=FNR{a[$1,$3]++;next}(a[$1,$3])' file1 file2. If i make the reverse way it prints file2 contents. but ideally i require both the files

Comment: you need to improve the quality of your Q per multiple comments above. Replying to requests for clarification in comments does not improve your Q. **please update  your Q** so we have A. a clear definition of your input, B. required output from that input, C. your code, D. your current output and E. any error messages. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$3]=$0}FNR!=NR{if(a[$1,$3])print a[$1,$3] "\n" $0}' f1 f2
```

First pattern stores a (the last only) line in the first file for a given 
1st & 3rd field.
Second pattern checks if the 1st & 3rd field in the second file was found in the first file and if so prints both.

(untested)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Is it possible to print as line by line instead of side by side

Comment: sure, I changed the comma to a newline in the print statement

Comment: I am curious, what is the aversion to sorting?

Comment: Thank you very much tomc. It works perfect. The source is unsorted file and huge sized. I am trying to find out the solution on using the same unsorted file instead of copy to temp file and sort.

Comment: I see, huge is different for different folks,  recommend you put the shorter file first

Answer (score 1):

solving with `awk` will require multiple passes and `gawk` sorted input option, here is a `grep` alternative

```
$ function f(){ grep -f <(cut -d'|' -f1 "$2") "$1"; }; f file1 file2; f file2 file1

a;c1|a|data
a;c2|a|data
b;c1|b|data
b;c1|b|data
a;c2|a_1|data
b;c1|b_1|data
b;c1|b_1|data
a;c1|a_1|data
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. But I am looking to compare the two un-sorted files with column 1 & 3 and print the output of both the files using the awk command. As i need to compare more records, looking for the awk command for comparison of un-sorted files.

Comment: column 3 says "data".  Are you sure it's part of the key?  The script above does it for first field only.  Doesn't require files to be sorted.  Note also that you have duplicate records (e.g. b;c1|b|data).